# Postgres timestamp formatting in query

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating a code with its own ORM from Db2 to postgres. I have a query that executes the following sql on postgres 10 -

```
SELECT * FROM TriggerQueue 
WHERE  TriggerQueue.atServerStartup = 'Y' 
AND (TriggerQueue.scheduledatetime > '2018-06-21 20.02.57.827' OR 
TriggerQueue.scheduleDateTime is null) AND TriggerQueue.inputQueue = 'N'
```

but the pgadmin is showing the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2018-06-21 
20.02.57.827"
LINE 3: AND (TriggerQueue.scheduledatetime > '2018-06-21 20.02.57.8...
                                             ^
SQL state: 22007
```

I'm guessing the timestamp format is wrong based on sql state, but I'm not sure how to format the value. Any insight on this would be very helpful.

EDIT : Timestamp field in pg is of the type timestamp without timezone. Pgadmin shows size of 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper [timestamp literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.19.7):

```
timestamp '2018-06-21 20:02:57.827'
```

Note the `:` to separate hours, minutes and seconds